# How can I extract a set of selected data from a string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to extract all the data with @sign in a PHP string and save it as an array. How can I do this?

**String:**

```
The quick @brown fox jumped over the lazy @dog near the @riverbank.
```

Desired output would be an array containing the strings with `@sign`:

```
$result = array('brown', 'dog', 'riverbank');
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try with `preg_match_all` php function

Comment: you could use a regex to find all words and then find all matches that start with the @ symbol, but unless you gives as the code you tried so far, we can't correct it.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Will try this one and post my results... :)

Comment: @user3218670  you can go through once with my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution, using [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
<?php
$str = "The quick @brown fox jumped over the lazy @dog near the @riverbank.";

preg_match_all("/(?:\@)([\w]+)/", $str, $arr);
var_dump($arr[1]);
```

**demo:** https://ideone.com/G5v3Jq

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the tips. I have slightly modified Sebastian's Brosch code with this one here:

```
$str = "The quick @brown fox jumped over the lazy @dog near the @riverbank.";

preg_match_all('~@.\w+~', $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

print_r($matches);
```